# ubuntu 16.04 included software

Tags: 16.04

where can I find a list with the included software for ubuntu 16.04.

I mean the software that I installed, when I install a brand new 16.04 and not the available software in the repository.

I can't find a list over google ...

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.manifest?

Answer (score 0):

I coudn't find it either.

Anyway, I think this link shows the most of the third party pre-installed softwares.
https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/features

Besides those, you have configurational softwares, like startup manager, disk manager, file explorer, this kind of stuff. All made by GNOME or Unity and all replaceble for any alternative you wish.

You also have more stuff pre-installed, but you can always replace any of them if you want. There are plenty of options.

Things that I can remember now that the link don't include:

Basics, by GNOME mostly:

- Torrent downloader
- PDF and Ebook reader
- Video transcoder
- Music/Video Player
- Image Viwer and Editor
- Scanner and printing
- Bluetooth manager
- Archive compressor

Third Party:

- Audacity
- Amazon
- Some basic games

I have installed a lot of stuff on my system and I'm can't be sure that those are all. Anyway, it can give you the general idea.

I hope I helped!